# Link for Linq - Even the right google question would be ok

Tags: c#, linq

I have a common problem for which an explanation would probably be too lengthy.  A good link for the information I need would be greatly appreciated.  I have googled but am not completely sure what I am looking for.

I have to search a database on the results of a form.  The user has about 20 options to select from, about 10 of which are text fields.  I want to provide them the ability to use a wildcard * character at the beginning and end of the text.  Further, if there are multiple terms I will interpret the space as a ||.

While writing a method for a single property is simple, generalizing it to many is difficult.  What I would like to do is create a private method which would look something like

```
func<string, bool> getClause(string val, Type property) { }
```

So if a user searches for someone with a FirstName of bob and a LastName of smith, I'd like to get each part of the query with

```
qry = qry.Where(
    getClause(FirstName, typeof(People.First)) &&
    getClause(LastName, typeof(People.Last)) && 
    ... );
```

I hope this is clear.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [dynamically build expression predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) or [dynamically build expression trees](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/26/to-bind-or-not-to-bind-dynamic-expression-trees-part-1.aspx), there is even a thing called [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) which I have also used. It looks like [dynamic searching using linq](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/08/29/implementing-dynamic-searching-using-linq.aspx) tries to resolve a similar problem as yours…

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is it.  The predicate builder is not sufficient because I'm operating on different properties but it's implementation is probably what I need to do.  After reading that I also found the following which is helpful.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) lets you assemble predicates to use in dynamic queries.

Comment: The predicate builder source code provides very useful insights.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you asked for, since performs an equality check and not a like, but it might point you into the right direction:

```
List<String> names = this.namesField.Text.Split(new Char[]() { ' ' }).ToList<String>();
List<String> surnames = this.surnamesField.Text.Split(new Char[]() { ' ' }).ToList<String>();

var query = from a in db.Persons
            where names.Contains(a.Name) && surnames.Contains(a.Surname)
            select a;
```

There should be a method similar to `List<T>.Contains()` which performs a partial match

**Disclaimer:** I have no access to Visual Studio right now so I'm writing this code by memory, typos may be included!

Comment: Thanks.  It is useful but not exactly what I need.